# Python find coordinates in 3d array of a value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3d array, I want to find the coordinate of every element with value 1.
I use numpy, and this is my array:

```
table = np.array([
    [
        [1,4,8,6],
        [8]],
    [
        [4],
        [9],
        [5]],
    [
        [6],
        [4]],
    [
        [2],
        [1]]])
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41434586/in-numpy-array-how-to-find-all-of-the-coordinates-of-a-value) related question I have the follow code:

```
print(np.argwhere(table == 1))
```

This code does exactly what I want (print 3d-coordinates of occurrences of value) for a 'simpler' 3d array.
But doesn't work for my array.

**Why does my current code not work on my array?
How to get the same result on my array?**

The array where it is working on:

```
table = np.array([
    [
        [ 1, 2, 3],
        [ 8, 4, 11]],
    [   
        [ 1, 4, 4],
        [ 8, 5, 9]],
    [
        [ 3, 8, 6],
        [ 11, 9, 8]],
    [   
        [ 3, 7, 6],
        [ 9, 3, 7]]])
```

Comment: Because that is an array of lists, numpy operations won't work on it directly

Comment: Check `table.shape, table.dtype`. It's probably not what you expect since the sublists don't have a common shape.

Comment: @a_guest thank you. Is there a way to achieve my goal with a variable shape? (something more elegant than for loops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you print your (first) *table*, the result is:

```
array([list([[1, 4, 8, 6], [8]]), list([[4], [9], [5]]), list([[6], [4]]),
       list([[2], [1]])], dtype=object)
```

i.e. it is a *1-D* array, containing 4 elements of *list* type.

The reason that *np.where* can't find instances of *1* is that
it looks at each element and compares it with the given value.
This function, when checking particular element of the array,
does **not** "dive" into this object (does not check individual
sub-elements of an element (if it is a list)).

All that *np.where* does when checking an element (of *list* type)
it to check: is this element == 1. Since it is not, then it treated
as non-matching. Other elements too.

## Edit following a comment as of 15.07

If you define your table as:

```
table2 = np.array(list([
    list([[1,4,8,6], [8,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]),
    list([[4,0,0,0], [9,0,0,0], [5,0,0,0]]),
    list([[6,0,0,0], [4,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]),
    list([[2,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]])]))
```

(with all lists of **same** size), *Pandas* is clever enough to convert
it to:

```
array([[[1, 4, 8, 6],
        [8, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[4, 0, 0, 0],
        [9, 0, 0, 0],
        [5, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[6, 0, 0, 0],
        [4, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[2, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

Run `table.shape` and you will see `(4, 3, 4)`.

Then run `table.dtype` and you will see `dtype('int32')`, so it is
now a "regular" *Numpy* array of *int*s.

In such case `np.argwhere(table == 1)` finds indices of cells
containing just **1**.

But your table is such a "weird" case that *Pandas* is not designed for.

To locate indices of each **1** in these (nested) lists, you may iterate
over your array (using *nd.iter*) and look inside each element for indices
of *1* if any. Something like:

```
it = np.nditer(table, flags=['f_index', 'refs_ok'])
for x in it:
    print(f'Index {it.index}: {x}')
    res = [(i, el.index(1)) for i, el in enumerate(x[()]) if 1 in el]
    if len(res) == 0:
        print('    Nothing found')
    else:
        print(f'    Found at: {res}')
```

Note that after *x* there is somewhat weird construction, namely *[()]*.
The reason is that:

- Your *table* is a *1-D* array of objects.
- Each element is actually a *0-D* array, containing a **single**
  object (a nested list).
- `[()]` is the way to get the only contained object. You access
  an element **by index**, but the index value is an **empty tuple**
  (no actual index value).

For your table the above code prints:

```
Index 0: [[1, 4, 8, 6], [8]]
    Found at: [(0, 0)]
Index 1: [[4], [9], [5]]
    Nothing found
Index 2: [[6], [4]]
    Nothing found
Index 3: [[2], [1]]
    Found at: [(1, 0)]
```

If needed, rework it to suit your needs.